# Voting on Catalyst with Ledger hardware wallet

Tags: wallet, catalyst, yoroi

Hey guys I really love the simple approach of just stacking my Ada with the safety and security in my ledger Nano X. But for some reason it does not seem to allow me to vote on catalyst projects. Will you guys enable this feature in the future?
I've read on some blog posts about transferring Ada from one wallet to another to vote before snapshots etc, but that seems very tedious to me.

Comment: This is a question better suited for the Cardano Forum than for Stack Exchange, which should be a technical Q&A site. I suggest asking this here - https://forum.cardano.org/

Comment: @EddHaigh I personnally think that it could be considered almost a technical question if phrased this way: "How to vote on Catalyst with a ledger wallet ?".

Answer (score 10):

Yes, firmwares updates for this feature has been already submitted to both [Trezor](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/pull/1564) and [Ledger](https://github.com/vacuumlabs/ledger-app-cardano-shelley/pull/65).

Now, it is up to them, when they will release an update of their firmware to their customers.

Edit: they are now both available in your favorite wallet :)